# DDD - modeling of similar categories with different behavior

Tags: domain-driven-design, data-modeling

I have a question related to modeling similar Class of objects in a DB:

Suppose in the database i have a list of clients which can be in different categories - eg. Client --> can be in Category1 ... Category10

now, Client in Category1 has some behavior that is specific only to that kind of client, but Clients in Category2...Category10 has common behavior.

Should I have separate class for each of different client categories (probably overkill), or should I have only 2 classes ClientCategory1 and ClientCategory2to10?

Is it better to model this as Client class and have inside property with Category type. Then this behavior that is specific to ClientCategory1 can do the check if(category==1){ only do in this case; } ? The problem with this approach is that Client class would hold methods that are sometimes applicable (only category1) and other methods would be applicable only for other categories.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I have separate class for each of different client categories (probably overkill), or should I have only 2 classes ClientCategory1 and ClientCategory2to10?

Neither. Use the [strategy pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy):

When creating a User (probably in the constructor) and when loading a user from the DB (in case your OR/M has a onLoad-kind-of callback) set the strategy:

(pseudo-code)

```
class User
   private UserCategory category
   private PaymentStrategy paymentStrategy

   constructor
      setStrategyAccordingToCategory()

   @OnEntityLoaded
   public onLoad
      setStrategyAccordingToCategory()

   private setStrategyAccordingToCategory
      if (this.category == Category1)
          paymentStrategy = new AllInclusivePaymentStrategy(this) // cat1 users get everything all-inclusive
      else
          paymentStrategy = new DefaultPaymentStrategy(this) // cat2-10 pay regularily

   public onPayment
      this.paymentStrategy.onPayment
```

EDIT:
The pseudo-code i posted is actually a bad example. The decision on payment strategy should not be done by the user itself but rather by the payment service. But you get the point, do you?

Comment: your solution is in fact my 3rd option (Is it better to model this as Client class and have inside property with Category type.). The problem I find with this is that I have to implement behaviors that are valid only for clients in category1 that are not applicable to clients in categories 2..10. eg. I cannot call ClientInCat1.doClientInCat1SpecificThing() without having option to call ClientInCat2to10.doClientInCat1SpecificThing().

Comment: If you cannot get around that you will have to use inheritance.

Comment: @marstato have you considered the approach through *Visitor* pattern?

Comment: @Laiv not specifically; how would you implement the visitor pattern in this case?
As i wrote in the edit: the PaymentService should decide what strategy to use; i think the visitor pattern is a good idea there but i did not consider it at the time because i didn't think about the details

Answer (score 0):

No, you will soon end up with an infinite number of classes.

Consider your Client object may have more than one type of category. (it really would be easier if people used real examples) Lets use animals

```
Skin : Furry, hairy, bald, scaley.. etc
Mobility : Running, Jumping, Flying.. etc
```

So now I have `SkinTypes * MobilityTypes` number of possible classes

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example I would recommend the object oriented way: have different classes for those two client types.

Another possibility you did not mention is to rework the design. Probably *client* can stay and you need to introduce *ClientCategory* which has 2 implementations at the moment.

But the example is very shallow and in my experience you need to decide from case to case.